# Blank pages of Laravel 5.1 on live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I uploaded all the files using FTP. Edited config/app.php accordingly to give my websites address (something like http://example.com)

I also have edited config/database.php accordingly to point my live db.

I have given permissions to storage and bootstrap/cache to 777

Laravel 5.1 require PHP >= 5.5.9 and my server has 5.5.29

I have enabled all the modules/extensions on server which are needed.

I have uploaded my files in /var/www/vhosts/example.com

But still I am getting blank pages. I guess I am missing something related to public or public_html but in my server there is no folder like public or public html it is /var/www/vhosts/example.com

Can anyone please help me what I am missing? I have tried available solutions but unable to resolve my problem.

**Edit:** I just figured out that in routes

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return 'Testing 123!';
});
```

is working but

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

is not working while the later code is working fine on localhost. Any guess friends?

Comment: php 5.5.29 might be causing issues. Check out [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/can-i-use-php-5529-with-laravel-51?page=1)

Comment: Are you using .env  file to configure db and other services? If so have you edited that?

Comment: If it is a dedicated server, try restarting the web server.

Comment: @kunoichi previously I had 5.4.* so I updated it to 5.5.29 which should work as Laravel 5.1 requires >= 5.5.9 plus i have edited .env as well so either way it is getting the same information. I have so many live websites on the server and traffic in thousands in a hour so can't restart but if restart is possible I ask my network guy to restart it.

Comment: I might be wrong about this. What is the project root in vhost conf file in your web server? If it is /var/ww/vhosts/example.com, you need a htaccess file to redirect to public/index.php.

Comment: 5.5.9 is greater than 5.5.29 :)

Comment: @kunoichi according to https://secure.php.net/releases/ 5.5.29 is greater than 5.5.9

Comment: And finally my problem solved, although i had assigned permissions to top level directories but somehow missed files inside the directories to assign necessary permissions.

Comment: Were you ever able to find an exact answer, i am having similar issues ? @AfzaalAhmad

Comment: @manshu it was about permissions of necessary directories, sub directories, and files within it. You need to give permissions to storage and bootstrap/cache directory and its sub-directories, necessary permissions.